# Query issue in Yii

Tags: php, database, yii

Yii beginner here. I am facing some problem with how to query the database with the scenario I have. Here is what my two tables look like. The reason category is maintained in a separate table is because a product can belong to **multiple** categories.

```
Product Table
-------------
id
product_name
product_desc
product_color
product_price


Category Table
--------------
id
product_category
product_id
```

A product can belong to multiple category.

Now, let's say I want to find the products of category 'xyz' with color 'blue'. I am not sure how do I query both the tables using two different models (or not) to achieve this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have many to many relationship where one product can belong to multiple categories and one category can belong to multiple products.

You will definitely need a third table

```
    Product Table
-------------
id
product_name
product_desc
product_color
product_price


Category Table
--------------
id
category_name


Product_Category Table
----------------------
product_category_id
product_id ( foreign key to Product->id )
category_id (foreign key to Category->id )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement simple query without having a model like this:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$sql = "SELECT .....";
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);            
$dataReader=$command->query();          
$rows=$dataReader->read();
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arfeen's solution is perfectly valid.

Although, I would assume that you have already read the official [Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) documentation on yii website.